# Are there attempts at fly-by-wire servo flap controlled rotor?

Tags: helicopter, rotorcraft, fly-by-wire, rotor-head

Reading this [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/32279/is-it-possible-to-design-a-helicopter-with-fixed-rotor-blades-only-no-blade-ang) and then this document about [servo flap controlled rotor](https://www.helis.com/howflies/servo.php)

I was wondering if there has been any attempt at building one fixed hub helicopter with twistable blades hosting at 75% span one electric servo motor actuating trailing edge flap, where cyclic and collective pitch adjustment is programmed in flight computer, instead of having a mechanical synchronization & actuation.

This could allow one simple rotor hub and rotor axis design, only including brushes or brushless things to transmit electrical needs to servo motors.

Mainly getting rid of this:

[image]
([source](http://oh1ninja.la.coocan.jp/details/KMAX/kmax_e.htm))

and using fly-by-wire? If not why?

Comment: While this might result in less complexity, I would imagine the task of running power and electrical control to the servos mounted on a rotor head moving at 350-450rpm might be problematic, also the issues with existing servo helos [slower response and slower top speeds] would likely not improve.

Comment: I agree constant centrifugal force on working servos has to be considered. But every electric engine since the first one, has to transmit electricity from stator to rotor, in this case rotor is helis rotor shaft